# Jetty: How to redirect base url?

Tags: centos, redirect, jetty

Scenario:

1. I'm using a jetty server.
2. I have a webapp running on: myip/myWebApp

Question: How to redirect base url to base url/something

ie. `http://190.23.30.1/` --> `http://190.23.30.1/mywebapp`

So when a user hits **`http://190.23.30.1/`** my server will redirect to **`http://190.23.30.1/myWebApp`**

Answer (score 1):

Jetty has a [Rewrite Handler](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/rewrite-handler.html) that can be enabled using

```
$ java -jar start.jar --add-to-start=rewrite`
```

Following the examples given in the documentation, you can add a rule in the xml file:

```
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Ref refid="Rewrite">
    <Call name="addRule">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RedirectPatternRule">
          <Set name="pattern" type="String"></Set>
          <Set name="location">/myWebApp/</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
  </Ref>
</Configure>
```

The equivalent for embedded Jetty configuration file would be:

```
Server server = new Server();
RewriteHandler rewrite = new RewriteHandler();

RedirectPatternRule redirect = new RedirectPatternRule();
redirect.setPattern("/");
redirect.setReplacement("/myWebApp/");
rewrite.addRule(redirect);
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a config based way to do this but a quick and dirty solution is to create an index page that redirects to the desired URL.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>MyWebApp</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/mywebapp'" />
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

- Create a 'root' directory in jetty: mkdir /webapps/root
- Create an index.html in /webapps/root/ with content like the above